# Вопрос по Yii2 aliases

Tags: yii2, laravel, yii

В Laravel есть система namespace псевдонимов, я захожу в файл config, прописываю там нужный мне namespace и указываю краткий псевдоним к нему, есть ли подобное в Yii2? Искал, так и не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно то, что вы искали https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-aliases.

Вот похожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797051/setting-aliases-in-yii2-within-the-app-config-file

Comment: Это псевдонимы для путей к файлам или URL адресам, меня же интересует, есть ли в Yii система namespace aliases, как в Laravel.

Comment: Пример, в Laravel я захожу в конфиг файл App, добавляю массив 
'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class.

И теперь вместо того чтобы писать в use полный путь, я могу прописать
use View.

Comment: Так вроде как нэймспэйсы и ввели для того, чтобы уйти от этого. А когда будет несколько View в разных местах проекта?

Comment: Псевдонимы создаются для основных классов проекта, которых обычно не очень много. Пространство имен же было введено из-за конфликта класссов. Например я создам класс User, подключу библиотеку, в которой так же будет класс User, в итоге получу ошибку.

Comment: если в одном месте подключается два класа с одинаковыми именами, то можно в парямо зздесь задать превдоним, например
use foo\bar\User;
use model\User as User1;